# Using Gekko in Python, for a multi-objective optimization problem, do all objective functions have to be of the same unit?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

As per Gekko documentation, multiple objective functions are summed and an overall objective value is solved for. Does this mean that all objective functions have to have the same dimension or unit (m3 or USD or kg)?
If so, is there a way to have multiple objectives with differing units?
Also, side question, is there an easy extract the optimal objective value for each objective function (aside from the overall objective value given by the solver)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gekko adds the objective functions together into a single objective statement. Gekko doesn't track units so something like `Maximize(flow1)` in `kg/hr` and `Maximize(flow2)` in `gm/hr` are not scaled by Gekko. Here is a simple example problem that shows how a multi-objective function statement can be solved:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Var()
obj1 = m.Intermediate((x-3)**2)
obj2 = m.Intermediate((x-2)**2)
m.Minimize(obj1)
m.Minimize(obj2)
m.solve(disp=False)
print('Obj Total: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
print('Obj1: ',obj1.value[0])
print('Obj2: ',obj2.value[0])
print('x: ',x.value[0])
```

The solution is `x=2.5`, as expected:

```
Obj Total:  0.5
Obj1:  0.25
Obj2:  0.25
x:  2.5
```

The two objectives are added together to create the overall objective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. So, if I'm understanding correctly, it is okay to have objective functions with different units. However, an issue I've been having is that the solution I'm getting is 'nan,' albeit successful. I'm inclined to believe that I somehow changed something in the settings, because I reran even my previously working optimization problems, they're also giving me a successful 'nan' objective value (even though they were previously giving me proper numerical objective values). Do you happen to know what I could've mistakenly done?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting this results. You can check the solution reports by opening the run folder with `m.open_folder()`. There is more information with `m.options.DIAGLEVEL=2`. It's also a good idea to upgrade to the latest version with `pip install gekko --upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Dr. Hedengren. Unfortunately, the problem is still recurring and I cannot figure out how to resolve it. I'm still quite new to Gekko and Python so that may be why. I'll be posting a separate question, and I hope I can get your feedback on the code. Your help is greatly appreciated.